# Remove citation from nameref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, citing, amsthm, nameref

I have some theorems/lemmas which have a reference in their name, like this:

```
\begin{lemma}[Park's Lemma~\textnormal{\protect{\cite{park}}}]\label{lemma:parks-lemma}
    This is Park's Lemma
\end{lemma}
```

Now when I reference this Lemma, I want to reference only the name, like this:

```
\nameref{lemma:parks-lemma}
```

Now I also get the citation in the name, every time I reference this lemma, which I don't want. Is there any way to tell nameref to skip this part? I am using `amsthm`.

Edit:
MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nameref}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@techreport{park,
  author    = {Park},
  title     = {Park's Lemma},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lemma}[Park's Lemma~\textnormal{\protect{\cite{park}}}]\label{lemma:parks-lemma}
        This is Park's Lemma
    \end{lemma}
    
    Check out \nameref{lemma:parks-lemma}!
    
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always it is better to provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is.

Comment: @daleif you are right, of course. I have adapted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nameref uses the package gettitlestring to process the title. You can change its expansion method and then define a command that is ignored in such a title (nameref is loaded by hyperref, so there is no need to load it again, and your \protect doesn't make much sense):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{references.bib}
@techreport{park,
  author    = {Park},
  title     = {Park's Lemma},
}
\end{filecontents}

\GetTitleStringSetup{expand=true}
\newcommand\gobbletext[1]{#1}
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{\def\gobbletext#1{}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lemma}[Park's Lemma\gobbletext{~\textnormal{\cite{park}}}]\label{lemma:parks-lemma}
        This is Park's Lemma
    \end{lemma}
    
    Check out \nameref{lemma:parks-lemma}!
    
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If only the cite is the problem you can also use the more simpler

```
\GetTitleStringSetup{expand=true}
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{\def\cite#1{}}
```

But then don't use the `~` as the space will survive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nameref}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@techreport{park,
  author    = {Park},
  title     = {Park's Lemma},
}
\end{filecontents}

\NewDocumentCommand\lemmacite{om}{%
  \unskip~\textnormal{\IfValueTF{#1}{\cite[#1]{#2}}{\cite{#2}}}%
}

\newcommand*{\lemmaref}[1]{%
  {\RenewDocumentCommand\lemmacite{om}{\unskip}\nameref{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lemma}[Park's Lemma \lemmacite{park}]\label{lemma:parks-lemma}
        This is Park's Lemma
    \end{lemma}
    
    Check out \lemmaref{lemma:parks-lemma}!
    
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

In `\lemmaref` command `\lemmacite` is locally redefined to not produce an output but even remove the last skip.

I know, currently it is not completely automatic, because you have to use the `\lemmacite` and `\lemmaref` instead of `\cite` and `\nameref`. However, maybe it could a first step to a completely automatic solution.